# Why is IP important?

Tags: complexity-theory

- Why is the complexity class IP important?
- What additional insights does this class give us that we could not get from NP or RP?

Comment: $\mathsf{IP}$ *as a class* is not that important. What *is* important is the notion of an interactive proof system (IPS). However, I feel like an entire *research article* could be written on all that was spawned by IPSs (MIPs, PCPs, ZK, PoK, ...). Also, not sure how (i.e., in what sense?) you wish to relate that to "insights" given by NP and RP. IPSs are an entirely different beast to simply TMs refurbished with non-determinism or randomness.